# Multiple JavaScript Onloads

Tags: javascript, onload

I am not a JS expert so any help on this would be appreciated. I have the below script that needs to run on the page, the first is a fix to prevent a white flash when the next iframes are loaded. The last portion of the script will load an iframe depending on css media screen (different size iframe for different view ports). Problem is that both, when combined, use an onload function and because there are two, only the last one is being applied and thus renders the first onload useless.

Any ideas on how I can get both of these to work?

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Prevent variables from being global      
(function () {

var div = document.createElement('div'),
    ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || 
          document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';

ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);

window.onload = function() {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}

})();
onload=function(){
var el1=document.getElementById("frameContainer")
el1.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_medium.html\"></iframe>"

var el2=document.getElementById("frameContainer_medium")
el2.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_medium.html\"> </iframe>"

var el3=document.getElementById("frameContainer_small")
el3.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_small.html\">    </iframe>"

var el4=document.getElementById("frameContainer_very_small")
el4.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_very_small.html\">    </iframe>"

}
</script>
```

Thanks,

B

Comment: `onload=..` *overwrites* the previous assignment to `window.onload` property. If using the inline `onload` handler, *combine* the event handlers (you can call out to separate functions) - but better, use non-inline events and/or a support library which does as much.

Comment: Create separate functions the run the them in the order you need inside the `onload` event. You don't need multiple events.

Comment: Are you opposed to adding jquery? It would make a lot of this code easier to reasonable it and it effortlessly deals with multiple event bindings.

Comment: Thank you all. I am still learning JS so any suggestions you make would be appreciated (the above was provided off of two websites to address the fix I needed) so anyone who is willing to show me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it all in one function, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Prevent variables from being global      
(function () {

    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || 
              document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);

    window.onload = function() {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

        var el1=document.getElementById("frameContainer");
        el1.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_medium.html\"></iframe>";

        var el2=document.getElementById("frameContainer_medium");
        el2.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_medium.html\"> </iframe>";

        var el3=document.getElementById("frameContainer_small");
        el3.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_small.html\">    </iframe>";

        var el4=document.getElementById("frameContainer_very_small");
        el4.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_very_small.html\">    </iframe>";
    };
})();
</script>
```

By the way, you are missing some ";".

Comment: Hi Pato, thanks for this, it is greatly appreciated - I will try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Pato, Thank you again. I have put replaced the code but the first portion (that fixes the white flash when the IFrames load) is not working. I am not sure what has changed but I cannot confirm why this is happening and/or if both scripts are loading successfully.